# How to run JCMD without JDK on a docker container with openJDK installed

Tags: java, docker, jcmd

I need to run JCMD on prod to monitor my application, but unfortunately I can't have a proper JDK in place so I need to run it with a JRE. I can add some dependencies, but not the whole jdk.

I'm using openJDK 8.

Does anyone know how to do it?

There was one question already posted here ([How to run jcmd without the JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644361/how-to-run-jcmd-without-the-jdk)), but the answer works for windows servers, not for linux OS in a docker container.

Answer (score 3):

In my personal experience `jcmd` from newer version of Java works with the older versions.
You can exploit the multi-stage build feature and have `jlink` elegantly package for you the (strictly) necessary files, please refer to this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jdk-hotspot

RUN ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jlink --module-path jmods --add-modules jdk.jcmd --output /jcmd 

FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jre-hotspot
        
COPY --from=0 /jcmd /jcmd
```

In case you prefer, I give you "an" answer for Java 8, using adoptopenjdk and multistage build

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jdk-hotspot

RUN mkdir -p /jcmd && \
    mkdir -p /jcmd/bin && \
    mkdir -p /jcmd/lib && \
    cp ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jcmd /jcmd/bin/jcmd && \
    cp -r ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/* /jcmd/lib


FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jre-hotspot
        
COPY --from=0 /jcmd ${JAVA_HOME}
```

in this case `jcmd` gets installed along the jre installation, in the same bin folder as java.

I tested both of them in both docker-desktop 20.10.7 and Mirantis (Docker Enterprise) 3.3.11.